# Show $f(x,y)=x^2\log(x^4+y^2)$ is differentiable at $\vec 0$

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

I have to show that $f$ is differentiable at $\vec 0$, where
$$
f(x,y)=x^2\log(x^4+y^2),
$$
and $f(0,0)=0$.

I’ve already shown that $f$ is continuous at $\vec 0$. I started off by calculation the first partial derivative:
$$
D_1f(\vec 0)=\lim_{t\to 0}t\log t^4.
$$
However, I don’t know how to calculate this limit even. I looked at the plot, and it seems that $D_f(\vec 0)=D_2f(\vec 0)=0$, so apparently $t$ goes faster to zero then $\log t^4$ goes to minus infinity. How can I show this? Can I use Taylor? Should I evaluate then at $x=1$? This would yield:
$$
\log x=(x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+O((x-1)^3).
$$
Is this the way to go? I've never expanded $\log x$ before like this, and I'm unsure if it's correct.

Comment: If $t \rightarrow 0$, why do you bother with "$\log t^4$ goes to minus infinity"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed the way to go, to compute that limit, try using L'Hopital's rule on: $$ \frac{log(t^n)}{(\frac1t)} $$ with $t$ tending to zero from above.
Hopefully this should suffice for you to complete the question.

Comment: Hm alright, I tried avoiding l'Hôspital, because we haven't had it officially in school, but I guess it's too easy not to use, in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the derivatives are continuous, then the function is differentiable.
So find the derivative with respect to $x$ in $(0,0)$:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^2\log(x^4+y^2)-0}{x-0}
$$
and compare it with the limit of the derivative function
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f'_x(x,y)=\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\left(2x\log(x^4+y^2)+\frac{4x^5}{x^4+y^2}\right)
$$
Do the same for $f'_y(x,y)$.

Comment: I'm having problems with calculating the first partial derivative. (See my original post)

Comment: @ShaVuklia: i wrote the formula for the derivative with respect to $x$, have you seen it?

Comment: I'm struggling to show that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}x\log(x^4+y^2)=0$. I can't use l'Hospital here right? Because we're dealing with two variables. I also can't say $\vert\log(x^4+y^2)\vert\leq\vert\log(x^4)\vert$, because $\log$ is negative in our neighbourhood about zero. Would you know a hint?

Comment: @ShaVuklia: see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258739/differentiability-of-x2-logx4y2-at-0-0)

Comment: @enzotib Would you be able to give me more information on your definition? My definition says that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ has continuous partial derivatives (same as yours), but then I'd compute the partial derivatives via the definition, so $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h,y) - f(x,y)}{h}$, which looks a lot different to yours.

Comment: @PaulWoch: first of all is the reverse, i.e. $(f'_x,f'_y\text{ continuous at a point })\implies(f\text{ differentiable at that point})$, but this is a theorem, not a definition. The definition is, synthetically  $\lim(\Delta f-\nabla f\cdot\Delta P)/|\Delta P|=0$. Moreover, calculating the partial derivatives is not enough, to check the continuity one should compare the result with the limit of the derivative function.

Answer (score 0):

It is sufficient to show that $f$ is continuous in a neighbourhoud of $\vec 0$ and that $f$ has continuous partial derivatives in a neighbourhoud of $\vec 0$.

Obviously, the only point where a problem could arise is in $\vec 0$. Since you showed that $f$ is continuous in this point, you only need to check that $$\frac{\delta f}{\delta x}$$ and $$\frac{\delta f}{\delta y}$$

are continuous in a neighbourhood of $\vec 0$, which isn't hard.

Comment: I do not fully understand your extra question, but here is the theorem I used: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_higher_dimensions

Comment: never mind my previous question! I misinterpreted your answer. I understand now what you did, thank you

Answer (score 0):

$t\log t^4=4t\log t\to 0$ as $t\to 0_+$  is a standard limit from high school.